# Experiencing "unable to connect to rabbitmq server (Connection timed out)" sometime

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq

This rabbitmq server has about 1,000 msg/seconds
There are multiple microservice written in nodejs and php.
But for php app, we sometime experiencing a problem stated this warning

`stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://RABBITSERVER:5672 (Connection timed out)`

It's like a couple times per day. But i expected it to be zero case.

Where should i start to debug?

In rabbitmq `startup_log` it's getting flooded by following log

```
Error in log handler
====================
Event: {info_report,<0.186.0>,
           {<0.26822.90>,progress,
            [{supervisor,{<0.26822.90>,rabbit_channel_sup}},
             {started,
                 [{pid,<0.26869.90>},
                  {name,limiter},
                  {mfargs,
                      {rabbit_limiter,start_link,
                          [{<<"54.169.1.173:52562 -> 128.199.88.0:5"...>>,
                            1}]}},
                  {restart_type,transient},
                  {shutdown,4294967295},
                  {child_type,worker}]}]}}
Error: function_clause
Stack trace: [{error_logger_file_h,write_event,
                  [{<0.1097.0>,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit-1.log",[]},
                   {info_report,<0.186.0>,
                       {<0.26822.90>,progress,
                        [{supervisor,{<0.26822.90>,rabbit_channel_sup}},
                         {started,
                             [{pid,<0.26869.90>},
                              {name,limiter},
                              {mfargs,
                                  {rabbit_limiter,start_link,
                                      [{<<"54.169.1.173:52562 -> 128.199.88.0:5672">>,
                                        1}]}},
                              {restart_type,transient},
                              {shutdown,4294967295},
                              {child_type,worker}]}]}}],
                  [{file,"error_logger_file_h.erl"},{line,113}]},
              {error_logger_file_h,handle_event,2,
                  [{file,"error_logger_file_h.erl"},{line,78}]},
              {rabbit_error_logger_file_h,safe_handle_event,3,[]},
              {gen_event,server_update,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,522}]},
              {gen_event,server_notify,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,504}]},
              {gen_event,server_notify,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,506}]},
              {gen_event,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,266}]},
              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]

Error in log handler
====================
Event: {info_report,<0.186.0>,
           {<0.26822.90>,progress,
            [{supervisor,{<0.26822.90>,rabbit_channel_sup}},
             {started,
                 [{pid,<0.26841.90>},
                  {name,channel},
                  {mfargs,
                      {rabbit_channel,start_link,
                          [1,<0.26838.90>,<0.26783.90>,<0.26838.90>,
                           <<"54.169.1.173:52562 -> 12"...>>,
                           rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                           {user,<<"sitemind"...>>,[administrator],[...]},
                           <<"/">>,
                           [{<<...>>,...},{...}|...],
                           <0.26844.90>,<0.26869.90>]}},
                  {restart_type,intrinsic},
                  {shutdown,4294967295},
                  {child_type,worker}]}]}}
Error: function_clause
Stack trace: [{error_logger_file_h,write_event,
               [{<0.1097.0>,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit-1.log",[]},
                {info_report,<0.186.0>,
                 {<0.26822.90>,progress,
                  [{supervisor,{<0.26822.90>,rabbit_channel_sup}},
                   {started,
                    [{pid,<0.26841.90>},
                     {name,channel},
                     {mfargs,
                      {rabbit_channel,start_link,
                       [1,<0.26838.90>,<0.26783.90>,<0.26838.90>,
                        <<"54.169.1.173:52562 -> 128.199.88.0:5672">>,
                        rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                        {user,<<"siteminder">>,
                         [administrator],
                         [{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},
                        <<"/">>,
                        [{<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true},
                         {<<"publisher_confirms">>,bool,true},
                         {<<"consumer_cancel_notify">>,bool,true},
                         {<<"exchange_exchange_bindings">>,bool,true},
                         {<<"basic.nack">>,bool,true},
                         {<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true}],
                        <0.26844.90>,<0.26869.90>]}},
                     {restart_type,intrinsic},
                     {shutdown,4294967295},
                     {child_type,worker}]}]}}],
               [{file,"error_logger_file_h.erl"},{line,113}]},
              {error_logger_file_h,handle_event,2,
               [{file,"error_logger_file_h.erl"},{line,78}]},
              {rabbit_error_logger_file_h,safe_handle_event,3,[]},
              {gen_event,server_update,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,522}]},
              {gen_event,server_notify,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,504}]},
              {gen_event,server_notify,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,506}]},
              {gen_event,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,266}]},
              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]
```

I'm using rabbitmq server version 3.5.4
erlang in my server is `R16B03-1`

Is there any tuning i could tweak? Should it be tweak in server or rabbitmq service.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you post the rabbitmq logs? 
I am pretty sure that it is a network configuration problem

Comment: @Gabriele i found this error in startup_log https://gist.github.com/chaintan17/5d48080ec79bd1634d2dbe6b06401e4c and this error in sasl log https://gist.github.com/chaintan17/2f31a7078010ec249269ccb7742881e3
It keep printing...

Comment: another error https://gist.github.com/chaintan17/23224ca831be7095012afe82afcc7236

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using rabbitmq server version 3.5.4